# Python- Pulling from a normal distribution with asymmetric error bars

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy, statistics

I'm trying to write code to pull a value randomly from a normal distribution with asymmetric error bars. Basically I'm trying to use the equivalent of np.random.normal but be able to define an upper and lower sigma that are not equal. I don't want to use scipy.stats.skewnorm because I don't know how skewed my distribution is in terms of one parameter, I only know the + and - error bars. How would I do this?

Thanks for the help good people of stackoverflow!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 0):

A simple heuristic is to sample from a density which is like N(mean, sigma1) up to mean and like N(mean, sigma2) beyond mean. First sample a uniform [0, 1] variable and if it's less than 1/2, pick the first, otherwise pick the second. Then sample from the chosen normal distribution. That will give you a number that's on the wrong side half the time -- when that happens, just return mean minus (sample - mean) (or mean plus (mean - sample), respectively) instead; that give you a sample on the other side of mean.

Comment: Should be return 'mean + abs(v2)' or 'mean - abs(v1)'. But histogram would be ugly - non-continuous at mean

Comment: Yes, sampling v1 from N(0, s1) and returning mean - abs(v1) or v2 from N(0, s2) and returning mean + abs(v2) is probably a simpler way to say it. Ugly? I dunno if that makes a difference; OP would have to say more about for what purpose they want this distribution.

Comment: I put my next comment as an answer, would appreciate if you look at it

Answer (score 0):

@ItsAMe, I cannot put graphs in my comments, so writing it up as an answer. While @RobertDodier answer is technically correct, you should understand what kind of distribution you're getting.

Below I plotted two gaussian joined at 0, but with different sigmas (error bars, sigmas = 2 and 0.7). Maybe this is what you really want, but for me it is hard to imagine what kind of process will produce or require to simulate with such strange distribution. Is it something like this really exists in nature or some models?

[image]

Comment: Yup, it's ugly. OP doesn't seem to be around, but if they return, I'll be interested to hear their comments.

Comment: Asymmetric error bars are fairly common in science, and assuming Gaussian distribution of the errors is as well. It's just very odd to conceptualize (as obvious by your plot). Thanks everyone!

Comment: @ItsAMe Sure they are. But usually they're coming from, say, truncated normal, or skewed normal, or some other distribution with non-zero 3rd moment.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd actually have the large fall in the blue curve. You'd expect gaussians meeting at the middle with different heights and widths but that sharp of a node at the bottom seems odd

Comment: @ItsAMe Well, with total integral equal to 1, and each half integrals equal to 1/2, smaller peak will have to have larger tail, just two gaussians glued together. I could send you the Python code to draw.